# Python incorrectly reads massive CSV file (60MB)

Tags: python, csv

I'm writing a class function that opens/analyzes a large CSV file (60MB).

In the CSV file, there are 13 "rows" (or categories, such as: Product, Issue, Consumer Complaint, Company name), and below each row, are thousands of cells filled with information.

This is my code right now:

```
class Company_Data:
    def __init__ (self, ID, Company, Company_Response):
        self.ID = ID
        self.Company = Company
        self.Company_Response = Company_Response

def Response_function (self):
    if self.Company_Response == "In progress":
        return "being resolved"
    elif self.Company_Response == "Closed with explanation":
        return "resolved with an explanation"
    else:
        return ("I don't know what sort of response the "+ self.Company + ""+ " gave to the complaint ID " +self.ID+ " .")


companies_list = []

company_file = open("Consumer_Complaints.csv","r")
for line in company_file:
    company_data =line.strip().split(sep=",")
    company = Company_Data(company_data[1], company_data[4])
    companies_list.append(company)
company_file.close()


for x in companies_list:
    print (x.Response_function())
```

And although the program sometimes prints the statement w/ correct company names, like:

"I don't know what sort of response the Transworld Systems INC gave to complaint ID 9999",

it also prints out lines like:

"I don't know what sort of response 4/23/2015 gave to complaint ID 9999"

In 4 of the 13 rows, there are blank cells which may be the reason why the date
is getting mixed up w/ the company time, but I'm not 100% sure the cause for
this error.

Comment: Have you tried using the `csv` module?

Comment: @AnthonySottile I have not but I'll certainly look into it. Is it possible to analyze large CSV files without using the module?

Comment: Please fix your code indentation. Please include __all__ the relevant class information in your code (`self.Company_Response` doesn't seem to be defined anywhere). Please post a sample of the csv file you are trying to process.

Comment: @OpenTheCSV The interface seems similar to yours, however I imagine the csv module handles the edgecases better than split: https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Comment: If it works for some of the data but not all, the problem is on your data - the format must be inconsistent.

Comment: This question lacks the necessary data to reproduce the **problem**. Please provide a failing line of the input.

Comment: @inspectorG4dget Here is the link to the CSV file / I'm not sure how to post a sample of it as a comment: http://catalog.data.gov/dataset/consumer-complaint-database#topic=consumer_navigation

Comment: @AnthonySottile Also it seems the latest CSV Module download was released in 2002... is it really compatible with modern Python?

Comment: `csv` is stdlib and PEP'd, I'd certainly trust it over `split()` any day.  `csv` isn't exactly a *new* or *changing* format either.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly the attributes you mentioned (Product, Issue, Consumer Complaint, Company name) would better be described as columns (usually the first line in a csv file).  Then each line below that is a row, and the delimited sections of the row are the cells.

The method you are using to read the data, i.e. simply reading out lines, and splitting them by a comma, is not going to work with every CSV file.    CSV files can contain commas within the cells themselves, not to mention the character that delimits rows in the file may also be contained in the value of a cell, and then you have to handle the escaping of those cells, and the escaping of the character that is used for escaping (and depending on the source of this CSV that could be done in an unusual way).   There isn't really an official spec on how CSV files should be formatted, there is however this document which comes close: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180   However if you have something purporting to be a CSV file there must surely be a sensible way to read the data.

My first thought in terms of debugging would be to output the values in companies_list and see if they even match up to the CSV file.  They probably don't, in which case the other stuff you have there is never going to work right.

You may need to use something to parse CSV files properly.